# ASP.NET MVC Generic Navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am searching for a method to develop a generic navigation for my ASP.NET MVC application.

For that, I created two tables:

**Categories**: Id, Name, Description

**CategoryTable**: Id, Category [Foreign on table categories], ParentCategory [Foreign on table categories]

I will use my helper table "CategoryTable", because one category like "action" could have two parent categorys like "Xbox" oder PlayStation".

First question: Is this the right way?

Second question: I have no idea how to loop my tables so that I can build a navigation. 
Does everyone know, where I can navigation examples or something that would help me?

Best regards

Comment: what do you mean by generic nav.Are you referring to entity framework

Comment: No, I am using ADO.NET with SQLClient, but encapsulated with ninject. My objects are returning with the ICollection Interface so that I can use LINQ. With generic I mean, it is not hard coded which categories I want to display on the site.

Comment: The right way or not - it depends on your requirements. If you need to display some tree-like structures then it can be right but it's better you to google about storing and retrieving tree-like structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use only one table avoiding joins for your requirement.

ParnetId will have  null value where there is no Parent

```
Categories: Id, Name, Description,ParentId (Foreign key on same table)
```

Comment: But in this case, you cannot have one category without duplicate category labels :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just have your two tables:

### Category

Id
Name
Description

### CategoryLink

Id 
CategoryId (Foreign on Category) 
ParentCategoryId (Foreign on Categories, this one can allow nulls)

Then you could use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to recursively retrieve all of the Categories.

You're best off putting that in a Stored Procedure, then you can call it in Entity Framework using something like:

```
context.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC getNavigation");
```

Comment: But in your case, you cannot have one category without duplicate category labels :-( Thank you for the Common Table Expression tip, I will try it after work at home ;-)

Comment: Can you please help me to build the query for the CTE? :-/ It's a bit of to complex for my SQL-Knowledge... What is if I discard the idea with the second table and create one table with the column "ParentId" and I have more then one "Action" categorie as child.. Still I have then the opportunity to display all products with the category "Action"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I had the oportunity to see in production, for this kind of tree that the leaves have more than one father, is to use tags. You can add a column to 'Action' that can contain a list of tags with all the fathers this leave belongs too. This way an Action will have one father but will be joined to many others though tags.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I will think about that :-)
I ask for myself how other website handle this. I think I'am not the only one who will get this solution?!